# Python and Boost - Trying to run vPython and getting __doc__ is read only error.

Tags: python, macos, boost, vpython

How to get vPython working?

I'm running on Mac OS X with Python 2.6 , and recently downloaded vPython. Upon installation it also installs the Boost libraries for Python. Now, when I try to import the vPython libraries ('visual'), the following occurs:

```
>>>import visual
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/visual/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    import cvisual
AttributeError: 'Boost.Python.StaticProperty' object attribute '__doc__' is read-only
```

After reading around I've found this could possibly be a serious bug, but I lack the technical know-how to implement (or indeed trust myself to even try and implement) any of the 'workarounds' posted on the interweb.

Does anyone know a decent fix for this? Or could someone walk me through (newbie style) how to implement any of the fixes.

I believe I have installed the latest Boost libraries from their svn trunk, although (very unhelpfully) I'm not 100% sure it was successful, and at the very least it definitely didn't work.

Comment: It looks like a bug in the vpython libraries, so technical knowledge or not, you should report it to the author(s). They can tell you what to do.

Comment: I believe it has already been reported, but I was wondering if anyone here knew any way of fixing it? The methods on the p&q sites are pretty well beyond me!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
from visual import *
```

If thats not working than possibly reinstall Python on your machine as well as vPython.